# how to specify an arbitrary surface for field average in openfoam?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, openfoam, error-estimation

So, I am running this openfoam simulation and I need areaAverage velocity and pressure on a surface,currently the entire plane is being read, I wan't to specify my own in sampleSurfaceDict,

```
new_plane
{
    type            faceSource;
    functionObjectLibs ("libfieldFunctionObjects.so");
    enabled         true;
    outputControl   timeStep;
    log             true;
    valueOutput     true;
    source          sampledSurface;
    //setFormat raw;
    surfaceFormat   vtk;


    sampledSurfaceDict
    {
        type            plane;    // always triangulated
        basePoint       (0   -1.5 0);
        normalVector    (0 -1 0);
    }
    operation       areaAverage;
    fields
    (
        p
        U
    );
}
```

is there a type circle? or a way to specify radius? in sampledSurfaceDict

```
sampledSurfaceDict
    {
        type            plane;    // always triangulated
        basePoint       (0   -1.5 0);
        normalVector    (0 -1 0);
    }
```

does anyone know about planeEquationDict?

Comment: I think this is best asked in the OpenFOAM forums or mailing lists.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth I tried asking in cfdonline openfoam subforum. is there a openfoam-user mailing list?

Comment: I don't know. But I'm sure openfoam.org or openfoam.com know.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth: OpenFOAM essentially sells support; there aren't any forums or mailing lists on their web sites, as far as I can tell, which limits sources of free support to third-party forums and providers, such as CFD Online or OPENFoam Extend. However, like here, sufficiently narrow technical questions regarding OpenFOAM may not be answered for a long time (if at all) on CFD Online because people may not have the expertise, and the documentation is left vague, ostensibly to induce people to pay for support.

Comment: Aw, awesome. I had not realized this. That isn't exactly the spirit of open source...

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, there is non such thing. But what you aim for should be fairly straight forward to implement, as long as you happen to have some experience with C++.

1. Locate the **circleSet** in the OpenFOAM source directory.
2. Make a local copy of it and rename it to something like **faceSetSet**.
3. Read the name of the **faceSet** you'd like to sample on.
4. Read the **faceSet**.
5. In each timestep, loop only over those faces and average the fields you'd like.

This is a very rudimentary and basic algorithm, you'd have to fill in the gaps. If you need more help, let me know.

Comment: OK, it is more than what I expected,let us say I implemented that functionality, how do I link to existing openfoam installation so that my current set-up is undisturbed? (I am basically running a variation on pimpleDyMFoam tut)

Comment: Compile the above into a dynamic library, add the following code to your controlDict (change the library name, to fit your freshly compiled library):

    libs("mylib.so");

That just links your library to the solver during runtime. No need to recompile the solver or change the functionality of it. Does this answer you question?

Comment: I will accept after I have done it.